# Convert an IGrafx Flowcharter file to Visio File

Tags: type-conversion, visio

I am desperately trying to convert a number of IGrafx (*.igx) files to Visio.  I have tried to export them as a DXF and a WMF file format but can’t seem to get them to open in Visio in a legible way.
I have so many of these that it isn’t feasible to rebuild them in Visio.  Does anyone know how to convert them?
Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no direct way to import `igx` into Visio. We wrote an `IGrapfx -> XML` export for one of our customer. Source code is available at: https://github.com/cfillies/igxexport which is used in http://www.semtalk.com to convert that afterwards to Visio